# Network computers not showing up but can still access them

Tags: networking, windows-8, samba

I'm having a weird issue with network discovery. From my Windows 8.1 PC, I can access my network computers by typing in their local IP into the explorer address bar (and they show up afterwards in the file tree) but they are not showing up in the Network. See attached screenshot for what I mean.

N.B.: BUMBLEBEE is the computer I am trying to access the other computers from

[image]

Interestingly, when I do the same from my laptop, every computer (including BUMBLEBEE) is showing up in the Network. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: open CMD.EXE, type `ipconfig /all` and please post what you see in `NODE TYPE:` (either unknown, peer-to-peer, hybrid or the other one)

Comment: `Node Type: Hybrid`